# Scraping the analysis page from yahoo-finance with python and beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, google-sheets, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am trying to make a python script using Beautiful Soup that scrapes https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PLTR/analysis?p=PLTR the symbols on my excel sheet will loop through the URL and grab the information in the red boxes (look at the image attached to this post)  and spit them out into a .csv file (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uznGb.png). Then later I can add them to my excel sheet and arrange them the way I want. What is the best way to do this?

Thank you,
Armando

I tried something like this:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Define the base URL
base_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/analysis?p={}'

# Define the worksheet details
sheet_name = 'Secondeon'
worksheet_name = '.ANALYST'
csv_filename = 'table_data.csv'

# Set up Google Sheets API credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# Open the workbook and worksheet
workbook = client.open(sheet_name)
worksheet = workbook.worksheet(worksheet_name)

# Get symbols from Column A starting from Row 2
symbols = worksheet.col_values(1)[1:]

# Create a CSV file and write the table data
with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    # Iterate through each symbol
    for symbol in symbols:
        # Construct the URL for the symbol
        url = base_url.format(symbol, symbol)

        # Send a GET request to the URL
        response = requests.get(url)

        # Parse the HTML content with BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        # Find the first <table> on the page
        table = soup.find('table')

        # Write the table headers as the first row in the CSV file
        headers = [th.text.strip() for th in table.find_all('th')]
        writer.writerow(headers)

        # Find the rows in the table and write the data
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            data = [td.text.strip() for td in row.find_all('td')]
            writer.writerow(data)

print('Data scraped and exported to CSV successfully.')
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.read_html` to parse the HTML document for tables to DataFrames and the filter the values you're looging for:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PLTR/analysis?p=PLTR"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0'}

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text)[0]
df = df.set_index('Earnings Estimate')
cols = ['Current Year (2023)', 'Next Year (2024)']

print(df.loc['Avg. Estimate', cols])
```

Prints:

```
Current Year (2023)    0.21
Next Year (2024)       0.25
Name: Avg. Estimate, dtype: float64
```